# left() function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to display only the hours of the time. The following script is my attempt to do the same.

**Example**:

```
select left(visittime,2) from records;
```

Here `visittime` contains:

```
10:00:00;
```

So I need to display only the 10 from it. I have tried by using above script but I am getting an error.

**Error**:

```
function left(time without time zone, integer) does not exist
```

Comment: That's a case for the manual rather than for SO: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Okay! Will take care next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select to_char(visittime, 'HH24') from records;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use the EXTRACT function, as below:

```
select extract(hour from visittime) from records;
```

**Reference**:

[Date/Time Functions and Operators on PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: You're welcome! The documentation on the website reference has a lot of information + examples for each function :-)